# Queries and sort, what should my mongo index look like

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to create proper indices on our mongo collections, but am unclear about how the index, the query, and the sort all interact.

If I have the following:

```
db.stuff.find({"userId":"10"}).sort({"created":1});
```

Should I have a compound index on userId, created. Or, should I have two separate indices one on userId, and another on create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB [cannot use index intersection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-intersection/#index-intersection-and-sort) to support a query like yours where the query conditions and the sort would require separate indexes.

So you'd want to use a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/), with `userId` first and `created` second, so that all the resulting docs are in one contiguous range of the index:

```
db.stuff.createIndex({userId: 1, created: 1})
```